# Adding nominatim control from sidebar in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, javascript, nominatim

I'm using the example
http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/search/map.control.searchnominatim.html to search with Nominatim.

I have a sidebar and I would like when I click the button in the sidebar (Figure 1), click on the search button (Figure 2) and show it as shown in Figure 3. Adding to the map, ok. But I would like the button not to be on the map fixed and only to be executed when I click on the button in the sidebar. Is it possible?

[image]

code snippet html sidebar

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:searchNominatim.select()" role="tab" title="Nominatim">
    <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

JS

```
// Set the search control 
var searchNominatim = new ol.control.SearchNominatim (
{   
    //  polygon: $("#polygon").prop("checked"),
        reverse: true,
        polygon: false,
        position: true, // Search, with priority to geo position
        title: "Busca",
        reverseTitle: "Clique no mapa...",
        placeholder: "Busca...",
//      target: $("#address > div").get(0)
});
var requestData = searchNominatim.requestData.bind(searchNominatim);
searchNominatim.requestData = function (s) {
    var data = requestData(s);
    data.countrycodes = 'br';
    data.citt
    return data;
};
map.addControl (searchNominatim);

// Select feature when click on the reference index
searchNominatim.on('select', function(e)
{   
//  sLayer.getSource().clear();
    // Check if we get a geojson to describe the search
    if (e.search.geojson) {
        var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        var f = format.readFeature(e.search.geojson, { dataProjection: "EPSG:4326", featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection() });
    //  sLayer.getSource().addFeature(f);
        var view = map.getView();
        var resolution = view.getResolutionForExtent(f.getGeometry().getExtent(), map.getSize());
        var zoom = view.getZoomForResolution(resolution);
        var center = ol.extent.getCenter(f.getGeometry().getExtent());
        // redraw before zoom
        setTimeout(function(){
                view.animate({
                center: center,
                zoom: Math.min (zoom, 16)
            });
        }, 100);
    }
    else {
        map.getView().animate({
            center:e.coordinate,
            zoom: Math.max (map.getView().getZoom(),16)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: And when you would hide search control after once being shown?

Comment: After doing the search, clicking the search button would hide the control, just like
the control already does, however, I would not like the control to remain on the map (Figure 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of initially adding search control to the map and then activating it from the sidebar, your sidebar function can be a toggle function, which adds/removes control from the map. Additionally search control should be removed after every search.

So relevant part of the code could look something like this:

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:toggleSearch()" role="tab" title="Nominatim">
    <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

JS:

```
var searchNominatim = new ol.control.SearchNominatim (
{
  .
  .
  .
});
var requestData = searchNominatim.requestData.bind(searchNominatim);
searchNominatim.requestData = function (s) {
  .
  .
  .
};

searchNominatim.on('select', function(e)
{
  .
  .
  .
  toggleSearch();
});

var searchActive = false;

function toggleSearch() {
  if (searchActive)
    map.removeControl(searchNominatim);
  else {
    map.addControl(searchNominatim);
  }
  searchActive = !searchActive;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I need. Just a note, on the line `seachActive = false;`, change to `searchActive = false;`